# How negative resistance feature of Tunnel Diode is used in oscillators?

Tags: diodes

How is the negative resistance feature of Tunnel Diodes used in oscillators with the help of this circuit diagram.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Circuit diagram - there could be several circuits where this would work. It's better if you provide the circuit and ask the question else this question is too broad to answer and comes down to opinions and/or favourite circuits.

Comment: See the diagram

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_resistance When the Negative resistance is greater than the circuit loss, power is provided, and in your circuit oscillation is sustained. Tunnel Diodes are hard to come by so consider a Lambda Diode ciucuit  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_diode You may like the explanation found here http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Theory/neg_resistance/negres.htm

Comment: Home made Negative Resistance Diode from galvanized sheet metal. Good for self learning 
http://www.sparkbangbuzz.com/els/zincosc-el.htm

Comment: Do not cross post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we short the diode for a bit, you can see that we have a regular LC circuit with some voltage applied; it will oscillate normally, but it will suffer from damping - because of Rp -and the oscillation will stop after a while. 
Now if we add the diode, the negative resistance will cancel Rp and the oscillation will be sustained. R1 and R2 voltage divider keeps the diode biased in the negative resistance region.